# How do I make a WrappingTextField fill the entire Window?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift

I have a Window and a WrappingTextField.

I want the WrappingTextField to *always* fill the entire Window. Even when the user is resizing the Window, and when it is in full screen.

No matter which options or constraints I choose in Auto Layout, it only resizes with the Window horizontally, but its height remains the same, even if the height of the Window grows.

How do I make it fill the entire Window, and stay that way?

Answer (score 1):

By *WrappingTextField* I'm assuming you mean an a standard `NSTextField` object with it's *Layout* set to *Wraps* within Interface Builder.

The resizing behaviour of an `NSTextField` is influenced by its *Content Hugging Priority*. By default Interface Builder sets this at `750` for the control's *Vertical* dimension, and this is probably what's preventing your text field from resizing the way you want it to. Give it a smaller value - like say `100` - and the problem should resolve.